# Remove Video Controls Only When Poster Displaying & Display When Video Plays

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Looking for a WordPress solution for hiding the video controls only when the poster displays NOT when the video starts playing.

I used this CSS but cannot find a class which is added only when the video plays or only when the poster displays.

```
.mejs-controls {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

None of the other answers i checked relate to the WordPress video player.

Comment: Can you share demo?

Comment: Here's the same player with the controls showing https://www.mediaelementjs.com/